# How to define composite primary key on code first

Tags: vb.net

Anyone, please help me to define composite primary key on code first, it cannot to define both property code as below:

```
Public Class TaskMapper
    Overridable Property TaskType As TaskType
    Overridable Property Task As Task
End Class

Public Class TaskType
    Inherits MasterData
End Class

Public Class Task
    Inherits MasterData
End Class

Public MustInherit Class MasterData
    Public Property Code() As String
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Status() As String
End Class

Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
     'on this command raised an error  
modelBuilder.Entity(Of TaskMapper).HasKey(Function(tm) New With {tm.Task.Code, tm.TaskType.Code})
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

now, I can solved this problem by code as below
Public Class TaskMapper
    'Public Property ID As Integer
     _
    Property TaskTypeCode As String
    Overridable Property TaskType As TaskType
     _
    Property TaskCode As String
    Overridable Property Task As Task
End Class

thanks a lot